# Sorting by date and time not working SQLITE3 and Python

Tags: python, sqlite

This is how I create table:

```
c.execute(f"""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'news_list' (
                  stuff text,
                  more_stuff text,
                  date_posted date,
                  UNIQUE(href)
                  )""")
```

and I created the date like this in another function and store it in DB:

```
date_posted = f'{year}-{month}-{day}'
```

Looking something like this '2018-04-12'

Because it is not generated, but extracted from a scraped list. So it is a string basically in python.

then I order it using this in another function:

```
c.execute("""SELECT *
             FROM news_list
             ORDER BY date(date_posted) DESC""")
```

It does absolutely nothing. Tables stay unchanged when I refresh the database, and it does not give any errors either. What am I doing wrong?

ditto for time.

Comment: `SELECT ... ORDER BY` will return the indicated rows in the specified order. It won't _alter_ your table.

Comment: How do I do that? Do I have to reinsert everything?

Comment: @TheProgramMAN123: why do you think you need to apply a specific order?

Answer (score 1):

Databases don't alter the order in which data is *stored*, because that'd make it inefficient to maintain the database structures. As data is inserted, updated or dropped from a table, the database engine will move data around as it sees fit to maintain efficiency.

Instead, ordering is applied to the data produced by a `SELECT` query. You need to specify an ordering for every query where ordering matters to your application.

The order used in any given `SELECT` does not affect the order of other queries or the stored rows order.